# Custom data-types?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'd like to customize some data types in table designer.

Here is what came up in my mind:

- TimeSpan
- Url - also this type should be a valid URL and display as link

Update, for `TimeSpan`, I've used `TimeSpan.Ticks`, but I'm looking for a better solution that will include custom display and validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 Extensibility Toolkit](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0dfaa2eb-3951-49e7-ade7-b9343761e1d2) is the place to start.

[Luminous LightSwitch Types](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/783483a4-3ad4-4831-a01f-bb409fe42085) already has a URL type, so you're halfway there.

For TimeSpan, you'll be creating a `1. LightSwitch Business Type`.  Use `System.Int64` as underlying type to represent `Ticks`.

You'll want to read the example on creating a business type, which should be in the PDF "cookbook" or [online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/lightswitch/hh304488).

Once you have the business type implemented, I'm 95% positive that you can designate a control which will be used to edit the value on the UI.  There are plenty of FREE TimeSpan picker controls in WP7 and WPF.  You can combine these solutions into a Silverlight version for LightSwitch usage.

[WP7 TimeSpanPicker in depth](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-TimeSpanPicker-in-depth)
[A TimeSpanPicker for Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2010/11/29/a-timespanpicker-for-windows-phone-7.aspx?PageIndex=1&PostSortBy=MostComments)
[Time Picker (WPF)](https://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/11/18/time-picker/)

p.s. Please, I ask but a simple thing, if/when you do find a solution to the TimeSpan; can you post the content online and provide a link in the comments below this answer.  The community would be highly grateful. :)

Comment: Thanks for linking to my Luminous Types! I'm going to have a look at how difficult it'd be to add a Timespan type to the existing types. I'll post here if I do manage to add one.